# Compatibility of Ubuntu bash and Anaconda

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, anaconda

I have been using Python for 2+ years but as I am doing more and more projects and look forward to deploying them at industrial scale, I have recently started to do 2 things:

1. Use virtual environments, which is very easy to do on `Anaconda`
2. Work on a `Ubuntu` bash, as I have discovered that it is way more convenient for some projects (typically a `rasa`chatbot) and I believe that the conditions are closer to those of the Linux server that will be used for deployment.

Hence my 2 questions:

a) Am I on the right path?

b) Is it possible to use my Anaconda python envs on my Ubuntu bash? There doesn't seem to be anything like `bin/activate` in those environments...

Comment: What is Ubuntu bash? Is that the default shell? That's completely separate from Anaconda, in fact, bash is a whole different language than Python. I don't know what you're asking. I've never heard of bash environments...

Comment: read the [bash faq](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for some basics about bash. It is a user shell program, from which you can launch any program contained in its `$PATH` env var (it may not be optimal, and other env-vars may need to be set for some programs). bash can call python scripts, and python can call bash scripts, so it all depends on what you're trying to do. Good luck. General Qs without code such this as really off-topic for S.O. Please read [help] and [mcve] before posting more Qs here. Good luck.